# How to load swf files in android game from S3

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, flash, amazon-s3

I Have an android game with 10 levels. The menu screen will have icons to load levels. Each levels is a seperate files like `level1.swf` to `level10.swf`. These files were loading okay in the game when it is hosted in GoDaddy.

**Problem**:
When I moved the files to S3 storage (Amazon Web Services), with `public` setting,
the file is downloading in the browser but the same file is not loading inside the game.

Any suggestions?

**I've tried** using both S3 URL formats..

- https://gamefolder.s3.amazonaws.com/level1.swf
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/gamefolder/level1.swf

and my results are:

- working in browser
- working in html page in website
- Not working in game

My crossdomain.xml is as below

```
<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

however, the files hosted in google storage is working fine

```
if(lev==2) 
{
    URLArray[1] ="https://storage.googleapis.com/reverie/andriod_assets1/Reverie_8.swf"
}
if(lev>=3) 
{
URLArray[1] ="https://game.s3.amazonaws.com/levels/level"+1+".swf"
}
```

the game could load and play Level 2
 the game could not load level 3

Comment: Download file to **File.applicationStorageDirectory** as data then load from there as SWF.

Comment: @Organis the same file is working if its hosted in godaddy, but not working in S3

Comment: Your links have an error. How are they _"working in browser"_? The problem is in your upload settings. Check [section c: Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-object-permissions.html). Also check that you're using the [correct EndPoint for your region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#apigateway_region).

Comment: All your AWS links show this error in (Chrome) browser: `<Message>All access to this object has been disabled</Message>`. The .swf at Google storage downloads okay. Again the problem is in your AWS settings. Make sure your S3 **bucket** has the  correct **endpoint** for your region. That's the XXX  in `xxx.amazonaws.com` url. If you are not in the USA then your bucket endpoint **is not** S3. Myself for 8 years, I had to use endpoint `eu-west` since am in England. Are you reading their on-screen instructions? Don't just quickly click OK to everything and then be surprised at locked file access.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the [endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html) you are using is correct.

However, the recommended practice would be to utilize `TransferUtility` in [AWS SDK for Android](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/storage) to access your S3 buckets.